# this = undefined in anonymous function in typescript

Tags: typescript

this is the workaround which obviously I shouldn't have used it in the first place. But when I debug the code - "this" equals undefined!!!

```
public loadByIds(raw:string):Promise<any> {
    const _this = this;
    this.ids = raw.split('\n');
    return this.api.getStones(this.ids).then( results => {
      _this.problems.notFound = results.notFound;
      _this.problems.removed = results.removed;
      (results.accounts as Array<any>).forEach( (account:AccountFlatModel) => {
        _this.accounts.push(account);
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Hi, can you provide a bit more context to it. Maybe have a snippet in TS Playground?

Comment: btw: you use arrow functions as callbacks, and arrow functions share parent's scope, thus you don't have to use ES5 approach of defining `_this` variable. Just keep using `this` in child's arrow functions scopes.

Comment: that is exactly the problem - I HAD TO to the _this workaround because this was simply undefined and i have no idea why. btw - i'ts after upgrading a project to angular 4